# Who altered Δ Hidden Forbidden Holy Ground and removed Aura's Statue?

Tags: .hack

in The World in Δ Hidden Forbidden Holy Ground (*.hack*) there was a statue of Aura wrapped in chains. in The World:R2 Hulle Granz Cathedral (*.hack//G.U*) has the same address (Δ Hidden Forbidden Holy Ground) and in it the statue is gone only leaving the chains behind.

in *.hack//ROOTS* Shino said that the statue was that of a Goddess who left the world which, according to Zefie, is more or less what her mother Aura did. but the statue wasn't Aura herself though as it didn't re-appear when she stopped her Twilight Knights from fighting during their battle against the members of Raven.

i recall reading that the backstory of The World:R2 one of the goddesses who is dead was supposed to represent Aura and CC Corp reclaiming their system from Harald Hoerwick and his work but i know that CC Corp Admins can't get rid of the Lost Grounds or even edit them.

So who was it that removed Aura's Statue in Δ Hidden Forbidden Holy Ground

Answer (score 1):

The creators of R:2 would have been the people to modify the area after the destruction of the original game. IPO I would think it was Piroshi specifically because of something he mentions about graphics the first time you meet him at the area. However... I think there's more to it than that.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtBW_liXkt4